# How do I easily and manually update a record in SQL Server containing quotes?

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-update

I have a record in SQL Server that needs to be updated and the text of the body looks something like this:

```
<p>Hello World<p>
<p><a href='foo.com'>I'm a link.</a></p>
<p><a href="foo.com">I'm another link.</a></p>
```

Normally, you just do an old Ctl-C, Ctl-V, but that ends up with

```
UPDATE MyTable SET BODY = '<p>Hello World<p><p><a href='http://bar.com/foo'>I'm a link.</a></p><p><a href="bar.com/baz">I'm another link.</a></p>'
```

Well, that ends up with the age old problem: quotes inside my text to be used will close off my string. I could go through and change all of them through a few mass replaces, but I wondered if anyone had a clever way of handling this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two single quotes:

```
UPDATE  MyTable
SET     BODY = '<p>Hello World<p><p><a href=''http://bar.com/foo''>I''m a link.</a></p><p><a href="bar.com/baz">I''m another link.</a></p>'
```

Comment: Do you mean, 2 single quotes, because it looks like that's what you've written?

Comment: Yes, two single quotes

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had created a much harder problem in my head than it turned out to be.